# RAILS_ENV, NODE_ENV independent Docker image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, docker, environment-variables, docker-image

I've got an image with a Rails application that sets `RAILS_ENV` before installing gems, node packages, precompiling assets.

I'm not sure, but I can imagine that `assets:precompile` would behave differently depending on the environment (minifying assets or not).

Can you imagine having to put anything environment specific into `Dockerfile`? Should I avoid that? I don't like the idea of having to have environment specific images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify `RAILS_ENV` at least for precompiling assets. Specifically for this command, not for the whole image. Or else assets would build with non-production settings, would have different fingerprints, not those expected by your target environment.

So, with regard to assets managed by `sprockets`, you're fine as long as your environments' `sprockets` settings match those of production environment.